# How to use python multiprocessing pool in continuous loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing library for executing a selenium script. My code is below :

```
#-- start and join multiple threads ---
thread_list = []
total_threads=10 #-- no of parallel threads
for i in range(total_threads):
    t = Process(target=get_browser_and_start, args=[url,nlp,pixel])
    thread_list.append(t)
    print "starting thread..."
    t.start()

for t in thread_list:
    print "joining existing thread..."
    t.join()
```

As I understood the `join()` function, it will wait for each process to complete. But I want that as soon as a process is released, it will be assigned another task to perform new function.

It can be understood like this:

Say 8 processes started in first instance.

```
no_of_tasks_to_perform = 100

for i in range(no_of_tasks_to_perform):
    processes start(8)
    if process no 2 finished executing, start new process
    maintain 8 process at any point of time till 
    "i" is <= no_of_tasks_to_perform
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of starting new processes every now and then, try to put all your tasks into a `multiprocessing.Queue()`, and start 8 **long-running processes**, in each process keep accessing the task queue to get new tasks and then do the job, until there's no task any more.

In your case, it's more like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def worker(queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        task = queue.get()

        # now start to work on your task
        get_browser_and_start(url,nlp,pixel) # url, nlp, pixel can be unpacked from task

def main():
    queue = Queue()

    # Now put tasks into queue
    no_of_tasks_to_perform = 100

    for i in range(no_of_tasks_to_perform):
        queue.put([url, nlp, pixel, ...]) 

    # Now start all processes
    process = Process(target=worker, args=(queue, ))
    process.start()
    ...
    process.join()
```

Comment: @shane , Where are the 8 processors in this setup?  Should it have been simply: `process.start(8)`.  I have a custom python module I source which I can initialize the class to establish the webDriver instance and then call my scraping function with the parameters in the queue.  But wouldn't I need to instantiate 8 different webDrivers into a pool - because I am wondering how one X-window frame buffer(Xvfb) and headless chromedriver instance can act as 8 different processes to execute a queue of tasks (in the thousands)?

Comment: In this setup, you actually manually start 8 processes (or whatever you want), and make each one a long-running process to continuously fetch new task, (instantiate browser and do stuff, in your case), e.g. `process1 = Process(target=worker, args=(queue, ))` ... `process8 ...`. It's a different setup if you want to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, you need to pass your function with `map`, but it's actually not as convenient in your case, especially when it comes to multiple parameters, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5442981/7405394

Comment: @shane , 'hmm... I missed the **bold text** in your opening sentence;  Sorry/Thanks.  Another option could be to [instantiate the webDriver inside the worker of the queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824273/multiprocessing-and-selenium-python#answer-39843502) and then roughly controlling the number of processes launched by timing the execution of the cue - allowing processes to die off while new ones come on. This actually helps me to better control the number of requests made per hour through a proxy switcher whereas the number of processors can vary due to the I/O and waits. (???)